# Некорретное отображение текста в хроме

Tags: google-chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это связано именно с моим аккаунтом, вопрос что не так?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

В настройках Google Сhrome (chrome://settings/) есть раздел «Внешний вид». В нем предпоследний пункт - «Настроить шрифты».
Возможно, у Вас там изменены шрифты. По умолчанию там стоят Times New Roman, Arial и Consolas 16 размера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: неа, пробовал не помогает, убедился что это именно настройки аккаунта влияют, в режиме инкогнито все норм

Comment: Да, странно конечно... Возможно, что-то из [этих советов](https://superuser.com/questions/821092/chromes-fonts-look-off) поможет?